# java.security.AccessControlException:access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "File path" "write" )

Tags: java, linux, windows, tomcat, securitymanager

I'm using tomcat security manager for my application. In my application, i have placed my running tomcat in

```
path: usr/local/tomcat-7/webapps/myapplication
```

And when i run my application i will logged all the actions in logger. That logger file is placed in another path

```
path:usr/local/tomcat-6/logs/mylogs.log (*this is not running server, just a folder named tomcat-6*)
```

When i run my application with security manager, it will throw this exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException:access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "usr/local/tomcat6/logs/mylogs.log" "write" ).
```

In My catalina.policy file i have gave this rule to grant permission to this file. But it doesn't works.

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/../tomcat-6/logs/-" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1: Login as root user

2: Go to `logs` directory

3: `chmod 644 mylogs.log`

Comment: for windows what i have to do

Comment: for windows right click in the file and change the permission.

Comment: i have given full access to the file. But no use. The error seems security manager prohibits the application to write into the external folder.

Comment: Will you give me any clue or examples to get the tomcat installation directory.

Comment: You posted the error in linux box. Why are you asking about windows?

Comment: I have solved thhis in linux, That's why i asked for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Change your java permission. read this[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

Comment: Will you give me any clue or examples to get the tomcat installation directory.

Comment: Wherever is server, there you have to provide permissions in java setup. If you are using applets in browser you will get same access/permission denied exception on client side also. If yes, at client also you have to provide permissions. read from tutorial link from previous comment.